# For loop not behaving as expected without nested do-while

Tags: c++

I wrote the following code to shuffle a deck of cards:

```
int i,j;  
for(int x=1;x<53;x++) {
   i=rand()%4;  
   j=rand()%13;  
   if(deck[i][j]=0)  
       deck[i][j]=x;
   else
       x--;
}
```

That didn't produce any result, whereas the following code produced results:

```
int i,j;  
for(int x=1;x<53;x++) {
    do {
        i=rand()%4;  
        j=rand()%13;
    } while(deck[i][j]!=0);  
    deck[i][j]=x   
}
```

What difference causes this?

Comment: What do you mean by *didn't produce any results*? What are you expecting, and what is actually happening?

Comment: `if(deck[i][j]=0)` is an assignment and therefore always true, use the comparison operator `==` and check again.

Comment: @sled, don't you mean "therefore always false" ?

Comment: @ Rob Adams: You got me! Zero assignment returns zero so it's falsey

Answer (score 7):

I didn't look at your logic fully, but `if(deck[i][j]=0)` smells like a problem.  Did you mean `if(deck[i][j]==0)`?

**EDIT** looking at it now, I'm not sure how you got the answer you got.  The bottom loop is picking a random i and j value, and making sure that `deck[i][j]` is 0 (or NULL I'm guessing).  When it finds a NULL value for [i][j], it assigns x to that.

In your loop, you are decrementing x if deck[i][j] is not null (assuming you meant `==` which I think you did).  The bottom loop doesn't touch X anywhere inside the body - only in the for condition.  Why did you decide to decrement x?

Answer (score 5):

The problem is, that in your

```
if(deck[i][j]=0)
```

you use = whereas you must use ==

The result of the  assignment operator(=) is a reference to the assigned object, in this case it's a reference to `deck[i][j]` which you just set to 0. Therefore, it's like you wrote `if(0)` or `if(false)`. That's why your if code never executes. hth

***As a side note, note that in C++ we have [std::random_shuffle](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/random_shuffle/) function which is in `<algorithm>` header***

Answer (score 4):

`if(deck[i][j]=0)` is not a comparison, use `==`

(it's now an assignment, and always false - the value of `(a=b)` is `b`, in this case b is 0, and 0 is false)

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if(deck[i][j]=0) //assigns 0 to deck[i][j]
```

with this line

```
if(deck[i][j]==0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to using assignment instead of comparison, your first loop will go on forever. The "if" will always evaluate to false (sadly int degrades to bool too easily) and so x will be decremented back each loop to where it was.

In any case though it is a very inefficient way to shuffle because you will be getting lots of collisions later on. What you should be doing is picking a random number from 0 to x with x decreasing, and swap the next vacant space with the card that lies in that position, after starting with an unshuffled pack.

i.e.:

Start with a pack with 52 spaces where position 0 holds 0, position 1 holds 1 etc.

Pick a number from 0 to 51 (inclusive).
whatever number comes up, swap what is there with what is in position 51 (which will be 51). eg if you get 17, put 17 into cell 51 and move 51 into cell 17.

Now pick a number from 0 to 50. Swap it with position 50, etc.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(deck[i][j]=0)
```

This is the problem. You wanted to write `==`.

That is why some guidelines recommend that one should write this as,

```
if( 0 == deck[i][j] )
```

Because accidental mistake would be caught in compilation time. I mean if you mistakenly write `=` instead of `==`, the code would not even compile!